# probability mass function of random variable in terms of probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Given P(X > k | X > k - 1)=$a_k$  for k=1,2,3....
>   Find PMF of X in terms of $a_k$.

To start this I could think of Bayes theorem which gets me nowhere. What else can I do to get going.

Comment: Please learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\mathbb{P}(X>k\vert X>k-1) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X>k)}{\mathbb{P}(X>k-1)} =ak$$

by Bayes Theorem. The numerator is $\mathbb{P}(X>k)$ because $\mathbb{P}(X>k, X>k-1) = \mathbb{P}(X>k)$

Multiplying through yeilds $$\mathbb{P}(X>k) = a_k\mathbb{P}(X>k-1)$$

Proceeding recursively gives us:

$$\mathbb{P}(X>k) = a_k\mathbb{P}(X>k-1) = a_ka_{k-1}\mathbb{P}(X>k-2) = ... = a_k \cdots a_1 \mathbb{P}(X>0) = a_k\cdots a_1$$

The last equality holds because the support is given as $k = 1, ...,$

This should be a good start, I think.

Comment: ak in the question is a subscript k.

Comment: Ah, ok. Fixed it.

Comment: since $a_k$ is a probability it lies between 0 and 1. Will there be any restrictions on this series of products? Like even if one of them is 0 the whole probability becomes 0!

Comment: Yup, they must all be nonzero and it must be the case that $\lim_k \prod_{n=1}^k a_n = 0$